# .net core api project routing issue

Tags: rest, web, asp.net-core

I am new to .net core and not very good with the routing understanding. I am trying to make api calls using the route template as follows

```
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}"
```

When I created the .net core project of api type, it added a controller with the name of Values and the way its accessing the api calls is placing the routes on top of the controller..   `[Route("api/[controller]")]`

How can I set my controller to use the action step?

I basically want to be able to make calls to my api like this

```
https://localhost:44345/api/MyProcessor/getValues
https://localhost:44345/api/MyProcessor/AllDefinations
```

Where MyProcessor is the name of the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to make calls to your api like:`https://localhost:port/api/[controllerName]/XXX`.

1.If the last `XXX` is defined to action. There are two options as
    follow:

Change the `[Route]` template:

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
```

Change `[HttpGet]` which is based on `[Route("api/[controller]")]`:

```
[HttpGet("[action]")]
```

2.If the last `XXX` is defined to any other name. You could change the `[HttpGet]` which is based on `[Route("api/[controller]")]`:

```
[HttpGet("getValues")]
```

Comment: Thanks Rena, I added the Rote template to  [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")], then I have  [HttpGet("Test")]
        public string Test()
        {
            return "Success";
        } When I make  a call like this https://localhost:44345/api/MyProcessor/Test.. Says page cant be found.. What am I missing here?

Comment: Hi Sarah,If you using this Route template and then have [HttpGet("Test")],your url should be https://localhost:44345/api/MyProcessor/Test/Test.

Comment: Thanks so very much Rena, that worked perfectly,, Appreciate your help on this.